# MlFlow - Unable to run with S3 as default-artifact-root

Tags: amazon-s3, docker-compose, mlflow

I am trying to store my model artifacts using mlflow to s3. In the API services, we use `MLFLOW_S3_ENDPOINT_URL` as the s3 bucket. In the mlflow service, we pass it as an environment variable. But, the mlflow container servicer fails with the below exception:

```
mflow_server  | botocore.exceptions.HTTPClientError: An HTTP Client raised an unhandled exception: Not supported URL scheme s3
```

docker-compose file as below:

```
version: "3.3"
services:
  prisim-api:
    image: prisim-api:latest
    container_name: prisim-api
    expose:
      - "8000"
    environment: 
    - S3_URL=s3://mlflow-automation-artifacts/
    - MLFLOW_SERVER=http://mlflow:5000
    - AWS_ID=xyz+
    - AWS_KEY=xyz

    networks:
      - prisim 
    depends_on:
      - mlflow
    links:
            - mlflow
    volumes:
      - app_data:/usr/data
  mlflow:
    image: mlflow_server:latest
    container_name: mflow_server
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"    
    environment:
      - AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=xyz+
      - AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=xyz
      - MLFLOW_S3_ENDPOINT_URL=s3://mlflow-automation-artifacts/
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "echo", "mlflow server is running"]
      interval: 1m30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 3
    networks:
       - prisim 
networks:
 prisim:
volumes:
  app_data:
```

Why the scheme s3 is not supported?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

I have added `["AWS_DEFAULT_REGION"]` to the environment variables and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

I have 0 experience with miflow, though what I see in the documentation is that you are using the wrong environment variable to set the S3 bucket. Or to be more precises, there seems to be no environment variable for what you try to do.

`MLFLOW_S3_ENDPOINT_URL` should be used in case you don't use AWS for S3 and is expecting a normal API url (starting with http/https). From the [documentation](https://www.mlflow.org/docs/latest/tracking.html):

> To store artifacts in a custom endpoint, set the `MLFLOW_S3_ENDPOINT_URL` to your endpoint’s URL. For example, if you have a MinIO server at 1.2.3.4 on port 9000:
>
> `export MLFLOW_S3_ENDPOINT_URL=http://1.2.3.4:9000`

I also came across a [github repository](https://github.com/flmu/mlflow-tracking-server/blob/master/) that creates docker images for the project. And they do it like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

set -e

if [ -z "$FILE_DIR" ]; then
  echo >&2 "FILE_DIR must be set"
  exit 1
fi

if [ -z "$AWS_BUCKET" ]; then
  echo >&2 "AWS_BUCKET must be set"
  exit 1
fi

mkdir -p "$FILE_DIR" && mlflow server \
    --backend-store-uri sqlite:///${FILE_DIR}/sqlite.db \
    --default-artifact-root s3://${AWS_BUCKET}/artifacts \
    --host 0.0.0.0 \
    --port $PORT
```

Searching about this flag, and an environment variable for it brought me to the same documentation, and it does not list an environment variable for it.

Besides that, I also came to a [code example](https://github.com/mlflow/mlflow/issues/3305#issuecomment-678787885) that lets you set the S3 bucket in code. So you could also parse the environment variable in code and set it like this:

```
import mlflow

mlfow.set_tracking_uri("your_postgres_uri")  # replace
expr_name = "new_experiment_2" # replace
s3_bucket = "your_s3_bucket_uri"  # replace

mllfow.create_experiment(expr_name, s3_bucket)
mlflow.set_experiment(expr_name)

with mlflow.start_run():
    # your code
```